# how do i bar plot a complete x axis and not just the last value

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I am bar plotting probabilities as a function of successes in binomial trials. I am getting in my figure the expected Y values but only the last x value, which should span from 0 to 10.
Here is my code:

```
close all; clc;

p = 0.2;
figure;

for j = 1:500

    for i = 1:10
        a = rand();
        success = fix(a*10);
        y = nchoosek(10,success)*(p^success)*(1-p)^(10-success);
        bar(success,y);
        hold on;
    end

end
```

Comment: you are calling `bar` from within your loop. I suggest to collect the results in an array then call `bar` only once with all your results.

Comment: But you are plotting 5000 ery small bars. What should each bar have? the `sum` of the total `y` values on each specific `success`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things half wrong and some completely wrong.

The biggest mistake is: you are plotting a single bar per iteration. You code ends up with 50000 bars one on top of the other. Also your code can be really vectorized.

```
p = 0.2;
figure;

% create lots of random numbers
a = rand(10000,1);
success = fix(a*10);

% nchoosek doesnt allow vectors , so lets loop
for ii=1:length(success)
    nch=nchoosek(10,success(ii));
end
% compute y
y = nch.*(p.^success).*(1-p).^(10-success);
```

Now, you have a lots of `y` for 10 different `success` values. My guess is that you want to sum all the values that correspond to the same `success` value. For that, the `accumarray` function was created in MATLAB.

```
ybar=accumarray(success+1,y);
% plot ybar for the unique values of success!
bar(unique(success),ybar);
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but because P=0.2, one would expect to get the highest results when success=2.

Comment: @Maguzi I have absolutely no idea what you are doing theoretically, I just fixed your code. You migth have an error in your `y` equation then

Comment: @Maguzi in your `y` equation-> `nchosek` will give bigger value the smaller `success` is. The rest of the equation will give a bigger value the smalle `success` is. This means that the bigger value will always be when `success` is smaller